# Pros & Cons of having multiple H1 elements

Tags: html, seo

I've got a page with multiple `<h1>`. It's a forum page and each category `(7x)` has a `<h1>` tag - same as the page title. Since the page title is not clearly specifying that it's a forum page, the categories became **equally** important.

Will that effect the `SEO` of the page?

Generally speaking, is it ok to have ***more than one  tag per page***?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: + 3 downvotes for me. Tried to help. See what bad questions do to us? And by the way, I still stick by my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5 having multiple `<h1>` tags is allowed. On SO it is generally considered bad to only post links to external resources (link rotting etc.) but I am going to go against that rule and post one really excellent recent article about using multiple `<h1>` tags.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era/

Comment: You can add as many -1 as you like, its not a hard written rule. Besides, the summary is right there in the first sentence "In HTML5 having multiple <h1> tags is allowed." so the next time you feel trigger happy please do take care to at least read the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

**`con` of using many:** 
You will get `flagged` for Google's spiders and your search rank will plummet if it sees them abused.

You should just use one `h1` for a title, perhaps some `h2`s for sub headings, and potentially `h3` for further down headings.

As described in this extended post on `stackexchange`:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15895/seo-regarding-using-multiple-h1-tag

But then again, it's from 3 years ago, so after reading the article from @holodoc, I'm now strangely intrigued at learning more. My answer appears to be for legacy browsers at this point.

Comment: Any citations/resources? Also, answers should sound authoritative .. requests for clarifications or musings make better comments.

Comment: Sure, if they're necessary. Uno momento (I really think the one Holodoc provided is an excellent one, but let me get my own right quick.)

Comment: This thread seems to sum it up quite nicely (added to answer).

Comment: Definitely agree to the citation thing. However, I would consider a non-authoritative comment at the base of the answer non-threatening to the information provided, as there could very well be a more recent update than what I have previously practiced. We all know how quickly the web changes :-) Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @all bring on the downvotes. I stick by my answer.

Comment: @Nicholas Hazel +1 for your efforts and intention... ;)